# Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$$Lambda$365/0x0000000100509440@5a8d3058

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Ive tried cleaning the whole set by running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` at the terminal, but the problem still persist. Don't know what else to do, although the problem started when I upgraded to flutter version 3.o.1
And it keep showing this

```
"Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$$Lambda$365/0x0000000100509440@5a8d3058.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\jars-9\77f1b6119df996df354847f2f9be857a' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin)."
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$$Lambda$368/0x000000010050a040@82b5f36.
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not add entry 'C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\jars-9\843b8db92378e58b7864a9be7e9c8ded' to cache file-access.bin (C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin).
 at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.put(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:162)
 at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.lambda$put$1(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:67)

Comment: that is the error that i was getting while work after upgrading to version 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#antivirus-impact:%7E:text=If%20your%20antivirus%20software%20has%20real%2Dtime%20scanning%20enabled%2C%20the%20antivirus%20can%20force%20the%20build%20process%20to%20halt%20each%20time%20a%20file%20is%20created%20while%20the%20antivirus%20scans%20that%20file.).

Your antivirus might be a cause. if not, try restarting your pc (your cache files might be locked in a process and restarting might free them up) if that still doesn't solve it, try manually deleting the mentioned cache files.

Comment: ive tried tracing the cache, i found none

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem after switching the flutter channel from **dev** to **stable**.
What worked for me is-

1. switch the flutter channel again to dev
2. after that switched to again stable.